The Euclidean and the Mahalanobis distance matrices are identical before and after rescaling to z scores? MDS clustering showed a liner pattern
I would like to run the representational similarity analysis (RSA) on BOLD fMRI data with a total of 35 subjects to compare the neural representation pattern in M1 brain region in 81 voxel for each patient. This is mainly a between subjects design for R hand drawing task and I'm looking in M1 left hemisphere (contralateral side) to the drawing hand (1 condition). I imported the data which is matrix of 35x81 which has the average of BOLD magnitude in each voxel for each subject.
I followed the steps described here to run the analysis using the rsatoolbox Python library
(https://github.com/rsagroup/rsatoolbox/blob/main/demos/demo_bootstrap.ipynb)
I loaded the data and then did the z score transformation. The mean was close to zero and the SD was 1  after the transformation. Please see my code below
My issues and questions:

Is it possible to have the Euclidean distance matrix and the Mahalanobis distance matrix to be identical? If not, what could be the issue and how to fix it?
Is any other data transformation or rescaling more recommended for this data?
The Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) of patients plot shows a liner relationship with no clustering. What could cause this liberality and how to fix it? The pattern on the dissimilarity matrix matched the pattern on the plot where patients in opposite extremes had high dissimilatory values and patients close together had lower dissimilarity values.

Thank you so much!
Below are all the steps and code with images of the visualization
mat_data = io.loadmat('matrix_task-drawRH_roi-M1_hemi-L_cope1.mat')
measurements = mat_data['rsaMatrix']
nSubj = measurements.shape[0]
nVox = measurements.shape[1]

# Print the shape of the data
print(f'Number of subjects: {nSubj}')
print(f'Number of voxels per subject: {nVox}')

# Ensure the dataset has the expected shape
assert nSubj == 35, f"Expected 35 subjects, but got {nSubj}"
assert nVox == 81, f"Expected 81 voxels per subject, but got {nVox}"
print(measurements)

# Calculate the mean and the SD of the measurement data  
# Standardize the data (z-score normalization)

means = np.mean(measurements, axis=0)
std_devs = np.std(measurements, axis=0)

print("Means of measurement:", np.mean(means)) # the mean was  
print("Standard deviations of measurement:", np.mean(std_devs))

# Standardize the data (z-score normalization)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_measurements_zscores = scaler.fit_transform(measurements)
print (scaled_measurements_zscores)

# Print the shape of the scaled data
print(f'Scaled number of subjects: {scaled_measurements_zscores.shape[0]}')
print(f'Scaled number of voxels per subject: {scaled_measurements_zscores.shape[1]}')


I chose to run the Euclidean distance matrix and the Mahalanobis distance metrics to compare between the them after I created the data object and both matrices were identical. I had the same results even before the rescaling of the data where the two matrices were identical although which to my knowledge should not be the case
# Create descriptors
des =  {'session': 1}
obs_des = {'observations':subject_ids}
chn_des = {'voxels': np.array(['voxel_' + str(x) for x in np.arange(1, nVox + 1)])}

print(f'Session descriptor: {des}')
print(f'Observation descriptor: {obs_des}')
print(f'Channel descriptor: {chn_des}')

data = rsd.Dataset(scaled_measurements_zscores, descriptors=des, obs_descriptors=obs_des, channel_descriptors=chn_des)

print(data) 

# Calculate the RDM using Euclidean Distance from the default method that calculates a squared matrix 
rdm_euclidean = rsr.calc_rdm(data, descriptor='observations')

# rdm_nonsquare = rsatoolbox.rdm.sqrt_transform(rdm)- We don't need this for now 

# Print the euclidean distance
print(rdm_euclidean)

# Use a different metric, we will use the mahalanobis distance
rdm_mahalanobis = rsr.calc_rdm(data, descriptor= 'observations', method='mahalanobis')
print(rdm_mahalanobis)

# Access the RDM contents
dist_vectors_mahalanobis = rdm_mahalanobis.get_vectors()
dist_matrix_mahalanobis = rdm_mahalanobis.get_matrices()

# Print the dissimilarity matrices 
print(dist_vectors_mahalanobis)
print(dist_matrix_mahalanobis)


Euclidean distance matrix
Mahalanobis distance matrix
Finally, I applied MDS on the Mahalanobis distance matrix to examine the clustering pattern of patients and the pattern was linear. First , I used the visualization method using the following code (I used both  , show MDS and iso functions and both resulted in the same pattern).
rsatoolbox.vis.scatter_plot.show_MDS(
    rdm_mahalanobis,
    pattern_descriptor='observations)

# Explicitly show the figure
plt.show()

Then I used the following approach which also resulted in the same pattern (see image under the code)
#Ensure the matrix is 2D and square
if dist_matrix_mahalanobis.ndim == 3:
    dist_matrix_mahalanobis = dist_matrix_mahalanobis[0]  # Take the first slice if 3D

assert dist_matrix_mahalanobis.shape[0] == dist_matrix_mahalanobis.shape[1], "Distance matrix is not square"

# Perform MDS
mds = MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity='precomputed', random_state=0)
mds_coords = mds.fit_transform(dist_matrix_mahalanobis)

# Create a figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, layout="constrained")

# Plot MDS results
ax.scatter(
    mds_coords[:, 0],
    mds_coords[:, 1],
    s=100,  # Size of the points
    facecolors="b",  # Single color since there's only one condition
    edgecolors="k"
)

# Customize the plot
ax.axis("off")
plt.title("MDS Visualization of Mahalanobis Distance Matrix")
plt.show()

MDS clustering of the Mahalanobis Distance Matrix
